# Rails: RSpec fails validations of model subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

I have a Rails 5 setup where RSpec fails to check validations on model subclass. If I manually build the object in console I am able to see the errors which should prevent the record to be valid.

**The base model:**

```rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: User

  validates :author, presence: { message: "L'utente autore dell'articolo è obbligatorio." }
  validates :title, presence: { message: "Il titolo dell'articolo è obbligatorio." }
end
```

**The model which inherits from Article:**

```rb
class LongArticle < Article
  mount_uploader :thumbnail, LongArticleThumbnailUploader

  validates :excerpt, presence: { message: "L'estratto dell'articolo è obbligatorio." }
  validates :thumbnail, presence: { message: "L'immagine di anteprima dell'articolo è obbligatoria." }
end
```

**The factory for these models (FactoryGirl):**

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
      association :author, factory: :author
      title "Giacomo Puccini: Tosca"

      factory :long_article do
          type "LongArticle"
          excerpt "<p>Teatro alla Scala: immenso Franco Corelli.</p>"
          thumbnail { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'images', 'unresized-long-article-thumbnail.jpg')) }
      end
  end
end
```

**This is the RSpec which doesn't work:**

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe LongArticle, type: :model do

  describe "is valid with mandatory fields" do
    it "should be valid with if all mandatory fields are filled" do
      article = FactoryGirl.create(:long_article)
      expect(article).to be_valid
    end

    it "should have an excerpt" do
      article = FactoryGirl.create(:long_article)
      article.excerpt = nil
      expect(article).not_to be_valid
    end
    it "should have the thumbnail" do
      article = FactoryGirl.create(:long_article)
      article.thumbnail = nil
      expect(article).not_to be_valid
    end
  end

end
```

The first spec pass, the other two don't.
I tried to test everything in the console, with the same values, and it works, meaning that the record is invalid as it should be.

Is it possible that with RSpec the validations in the subclass won't work?

Comment: While you're figuring out, I suggest you check out https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers to easily test validations.

Comment: You can also use debugger or biding.pry into the spec and manually run `article.valid?` to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for the delay, but I think I have figured out what was breaking my tests.

The problems, actually, were two, and not one as I originally thought.

**The first test: `should have an excerpt`**

As suggested by juanitofatas, I have added a `byebug` line after the one where FactoryGirl builds my model. I have noticed that the model instantiated had class `Article` and not `LongArticle`.

I came up noticing that FactoryGirl instantiate a model of the base factory when it first met `factory :article do`. Then, it adds or overrides the attributes defined into inner factories and treating the `type` attribute as any one other, ignoring that it drives the STI.

The `LongArticle` factory should have been defined as a completely different model, at the same level as the `Article` one is.

**The second test: `should have the thumbnail`**

This was a bit silly... I have defined a `default_url` method in the CarrierWave uploader and, in fact, this is the desired behavior. Test was updated.